# Convert a search query into 1's and 0's and use as a variable

Tags: php, mysql

Hello everyone and thanks for the time you will spend on this question.

### Problem

I am trying to convert my search query into 1's and 0's to check for a match inside my database.

Basically, I fill my form input with this query: **SF12345**

The code checks for each chars if it's numeric. If it is, it outputs a 1 if not it outputs a 0. So my code (SO's code :) ) so far will output **0011111**. So far, so good:

```
            $s = "SF12345";
        
            for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($s); $i++){
                
               $char = $s[$i];
               
               if (is_numeric($char)) {
                  echo "1";
               } else {
                  echo "0";
               }
            }
```

### Question

How do I "implode" or "regroup" all these echo's to use as one variable inside my search query below

```
$dbConn->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE code = '".$s.'");
```

I want it to look like this

```
$dbConn->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE code = '0011111'");
```

If anyone has any idea on how to approach or solve this issue, you'll make one (very) happy man.

If it is important to know why I want to convert it to 1's and 0's I'll be glad to explain.

Thank you very much, all help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could append to a string in PHP with the concatenating assignment operator `.=`. (See https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php for more information). Then you could do this:

```
$s = "SF12345";
$output = ""; // This will store the result. 

for ($i = 0;$i < strlen($s);$i++)
{

    $char = $s[$i];

    if (is_numeric($char))
    {
        $output .= "1";
    }
    else
    {
        $output .= "0";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It did exactly what I need it. Did not think if this solution, i remember using this method for PDF templates... Thanks a lot!